# How to initialize array of objects with the same value in constructor

Tags: c++, arrays, constructor

I am trying to initialize array of objects with the same value

```
class A
{
   A(int a1)
   {
      var1 = a1;
   }

   var1;
}

int main(void)
{
    // I want to initialize all the objects with 5 without using an array 
    A *arr = new A[10](5); // How to use the constructor to do something like this
    return 0;
}
```

As i want to pass the same value to all the objects, is there a way to avoid using an array. i.e. I want to avoid doing the following:

```
A *arr = new A[10]{5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5}
```

Comment: The easy answer is to use a vector, but I assume that's out of the question for some reason.

Comment: Since it is an `int` array, how about a simple `memset()` call?

Comment: @chris yes vector is not an option for me for some reason.

Comment: @REACHUS the int is just for example. The actual array can be pretty large with some other params in constructor so I was trying to see if the unnecessary memory can be avoided.

Comment: Or [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) which has a [`fill`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/fill) function?

Comment: Oh, I guess if vector is out so is array...

Comment: @REACHUS `memset` is _not_ appropriate for modern C++.  It is used for `char` arrays.  This question is about constructing a arbitrary datatype and filling it, which `memset` cannot do.  The closest alternative is `std::fill_n`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normally we avoid raw pointers, especially when not encapsulated in [`std::unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) or other automatic (RAII) pointer types.

Your first choice should be [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) if size is known at compile time, or [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) if you want dynamic size or a very large array.

The second choice, if you insist on managing the memory yourself, is to use [`std::fill`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/fill) or [`std::fill_n`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/fill_n) from [`<algorithm>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm).

In this case, `std::fill_n` is probably cleaner:

```
A *arr = new A[10];
std::fill_n( &arr[0], 10, A(5) );
```

Please at least consider automatic pointer management though:

```
std::unique_ptr<A[]> arr( new A[10] );
std::fill_n( &arr[0], 10, A(5) );
```